# Bring a horse in a dungeon

Tags: pathfinder-1e

I'm playing a Human Cavalier, order of the tome and I was looking for a build that would allow me to do mounted charges in dungeons.

I have found spells like Dust form and Sonic form that allow a Large creature to fit in a smaller space but they are too expensive and too short in duration.

I could also use shrink person and animal, but I am trying to stay Medium sized.

I was thinking. Is there a spell that would allow a medium sized mount to carry me ? Or a spectral mount that I could ride ?
Or even a sort of fly spell that would count as mounted combat ?

Thanks !

Comment: I can't help but think of Bill the Pony here.

Comment: Note that many GMs portray horses as reluctant to go underground, so you should definitely run any idea past your GM; It'd be very frustrating to come up with a build that lets you avoid hitting your head on the ceiling only to discover you can't take the horse any place where it would come up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to get your mount the universal monster ability [*Compression*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/universal-monster-rules#TOC-Compression-Ex-), or an equivalent effect.  There are several reliable ways of doing this:

1) Choose an appropriate mount:
 This is actually surprisingly difficult to do, if we limit ourselves to just normal animals listed for use as mounts by medium humanoids the only option is the Dire Weasel, though a Young Ogre Spider would work extremely well for characters with the ability to handle vermin/spiders (and would definitely be worth spending a feat on).

- [Young](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/templates/simple-template-young-cr-1) [Ogre Spider](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/vermin/spider/spider-ogre)
- [Dire Weasel](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/animals/weasel/weasel-dire)

2) Use spells (there's basically only one realistic option here):

- [*Squeeze*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/squeeze) replicates the Compression ability without referencing it, so the effects actually stack.  It's a second level racial spell that lasts 1 min/level and provides immunity against hostile polymorph effects (like any other polymorph spell).  Interestingly, the stacking means that you could use this with a full grown Ogre Spider and have a Huge sized mount.

3) Use feats

- Use any of the methods of bypassing racial prerequisites for feats to gain [Racial Heritage (Serpentfolk)](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/racial-feats/racial-heritage) and [Serpentine Compression](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/serpentine-compression) for your mount.
- Have your mount take [Narrow Frame](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/narrow-frame) and possibly [Lithe Attacker](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/lithe-attacker).  This combination is less good than the above set.

4) Use Magic Items

- As mentioned in another answer, the [*Belt of the Weasel*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/a-b/belt-of-the-weasel) does this and occupies a convenient slot, but it costs 10,000 gp.
- A [*Master's Squeezebox*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/m-p/master-s-squeeze-box) lets you do this whenever you want and for cheaper (6,000 gp), but it works only when held in a hand (though it is a slotless item). Use with a method of adding hands to your mount (e.g. [Extra Item Slot](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/extra-item-slot)).

Comment: Undersized Mount feat for a Medium-sized mount could also be helpful to conserve space. 

 http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/undersized-mount-combat

Comment: A Permanent Squeeze spell on my horse did the trick ! A real game changer for my Cavalier !

Answer (score 8):

The best option for someone who really wants to perform medium-sized mounted combat in dungeons might be a [belt of the weasel](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/a-b/belt-of-the-weasel), though it is price prohibitive at early levels. Another option is to take [Undersized Mount](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/undersized-mount-combat) as a bonus feat, though you'll have to be careful with encumbrance. Wands of [Reduce Animal](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/r/reduce-animal) can also be your friend, but mostly for moving your mount around, less so for using your mount as a mount, unless you also use a wand of [Reduce Person](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/r/reduce-person), but at that point you should probably just play a small creature.

Personally, I would recommend a Halfling Gecko Rider, or Halfling Wolf Lancer build for a dungeon-going Cavalier, if you really like mounted combat.